# What is a reliable method to create a 64-bit WIN7 pro installer (DVD or USB) that boots on (U)EFI systems?

Tags: windows-7, boot, uefi, efi

I am failing to start the Win7 pro installer in (U)EFI mode. I know that there are many instructions out there but can someone please point me to a really working solution.

Goal: Burn DVD or write USB drive with a 64 bit Win7 image that boots an (U)EFI system.

Thanks! Matt.

Comment: I have a 100% track record with [Rufus](http://rufus.akeo.ie/) personally.

Comment: Do you modify the content of the USB that Rufus creates in order to be able to boot it on a UEFI system?

Comment: What do you mean modify the contents of the USB?  I just provide it the 64-bit Windows 7 Service Pack 1 .ISO I downloaded directly from Microsoft.

Comment: how about an easy PXE network boot alternative instead of burning DVDs or creating Pendrives??

Comment: How would PXE boot work in this case?

Comment: Any recommendation on which PXE server to use on my Linux workstation?